# DELETE statement conflicted with Reference constraints in SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms, sql-delete

My Employee table has the Primary key Column that is (`EmpID`) which is referenced in two Other tables
`EmployeeEducation` table and `EmployeeBankInformation` table.

I want to Delete Employee against their ID but as I run the Stored Procedure my controller throws the error that the foreign key reference constraint conflicts because of the `EmpID` column.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[RemoveEmployee]
(
    @EmpID int
)
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM Employee WHERE EmpID = @EmpID
    DELETE FROM EmployeeEducation WHERE EmpID = @EmpID
    DELETE FROM EmployeeBankInformation WHERE EmpID = @EmpID
END
```

Where am I going wrong? Can any of you tell what mistake I am making in my procedure?

Comment: You need to `DELETE` from the tables that reference `Employee` as a Foreign Key *first* and then `DELETE` from the table `Employee`. It's no good deleting the row in `Employee` first, as that causes the foreign key constraint in the tables `EmployeeEducation` and `EmployeeBankInformation` to fail.

Comment: Side note: *Always* schema qualify your objects. Don't rely on the `USER`'s default schema being the right one.

Comment: @Larnu you means to say that what I have written above I just write those statement in reverse

Comment: Sort of. It likely (I can't be sure, as I don't have the definition of your tables) doesn't matter if you `DELETE` from `EmployeeEducation` or `EmployeeBankInformation` first, but it *does* matter that you delete from `Employee` *last*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close, just need to remove the employee last:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[RemoveEmployee]
(
    @EmpID int
)
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM EmployeeBankInformation WHERE EmpID = @EmpID
    DELETE FROM EmployeeEducation WHERE EmpID = @EmpID
    DELETE FROM Employee WHERE EmpID = @EmpID
END
```

Comment: maybe wraps those in a transaction....

Comment: Or at least set `XACT_ABORT` to `ON`.

Comment: If it worked, @SyedMuhammadAousajaAli , you should accept the answer as the solution to let future readers know the answer was helpful.